# How do I share all my itunes music with a friend?

Tags: itunes

I would like to share my whole iTunes library with a friend. He also has an ipod so I take it he also has iTunes on his pc ( with his own apple account and Id ). My library is just under 7 gig and I was thinking of using a usb memory stick. Will he be able to add all my music to his existing library, and vice versa?

Comment: Legally? ...No.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have "Copy files to iTunes Media folder" enabled in your "iTunes Preferences", you can find all all your files under:

```
/Users/yourUserName/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media
```

[image]

Comment: I believe this will only be valid for future imports, to copy all previous imports, if it wasn't on before, do as follows. Choose File > Library > Organize Library, and, in the window that displays, check Consolidate Files, and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could also open itunes, hit Command + A, and drag and drop the songs onto a flash drive.